# How to add an initial comment to a thread is opened for the first time

Tags: vscode-extensions

Are there any ways to add an initial comment to a thread opened for the first time?
Let me explain what I want to do with the screenshot below.
I am developing an extension that can collaborate with the Azure OpenAI. Then you can see the first comment "Let me ask about the code below ..." in the picture. I want to add this comment automatically when a thread is opened for the first time.

[image]

Here is the code I am using now...

```
<code>
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand(
        "hello-world.comment",
        async (reply: vscode.CommentReply) => {
            const question = reply.text;
            const thread = reply.thread;
            const messages: { role: string; content: string }[] = [];
            thread.comments.forEach((comment) => {
                messages.push({
                    role: comment.author.name,
                    content: comment.body.toString().trim(),
                });
            });
            messages.push({ role: "user", content: question.trim() });

            const newYourComment = new NoteComment(
                question,
                vscode.CommentMode.Preview,
                you,
                thread,
                "canDelete"
            );
            thread.comments = [...thread.comments, newYourComment];

            let response = "";
            const events = client.listChatCompletions(
                deploymentId,
                messages,
                chatOption
            );
            for await (const event of events) {
                for await (const choice of event.choices) {
                     const delta = choice.delta?.content;
                     if (delta !== undefined) {
                         response += delta;
                         // console.log(`Chatbot: ${delta}`);
                     }
                }
            }

            const newAIComment = new NoteComment(
                new vscode.MarkdownString(response),
                vscode.CommentMode.Preview,
                ai,
                thread,
                "canDelete"
            );
            thread.comments = [...thread.comments, newAIComment];
        }
    )
);
</code>
```

any help would be appreciated.
Akira
PS ... this code is inspired by https://github.com/ajikan/ScribeAI#-features